# Application installation service is went to paused state

Tags: sharepoint-server

In our SharePoint 2019 production environment, we are unable to install App and Remove App as getting error.  We could see that Application Installation Service timer job is went to paused state. Checked in ULS logs , the error at the specific time stamp is 
"Completed processing of timer job [job-app-install-queue] with lock type [None] against target instance. Status result: [Paused]"

"Completed processing of timer job [UnifiedPolicyFileSyncUrgentJobDefinition] with lock type [ContentDatabase] against target instance  Status result: [Paused]. Status ressage (if any): []."

Please help me to find the cause of this issue and how can we bring back the "Application Installation Service" timer job to success state and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the PowerShell command to restore the Default Farm-Scoped timer jobs:

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$farm.TimerService.EnsureDefaultJobs()
```

Restart the SharePoint Timer service via Run->services.msc.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the above steps. But after executing them also no luck still same issue. Also the issue specific for " SharePoint Store " Apps and they are showing as still adding to site contents from last 2 days.